# API is getting called on every click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I have created one quiz application. The questions and answers are coming from backend API. On the browser window whenever I am clicking any answer, API is getting called again. On every click API is getting called. How to resolve this. Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried `useEffect`, use state, but no success.
Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Quiz.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function Quiz() {

    const [cname, scname] = useState([]);
  const [results, finalres] = useState(false);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [currentQues, setCurrentQues] = useState(0);
   //Get Method
   useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/capital")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        scname(data.data);
      });
  }, []);

const restartGame = () => {
    setScore(0);
    setCurrentQues(0);
    finalres(false);
shuffledAnswers(currentQues);

  };
  let namearray = [5];
  var capitalArray = [5];

  let fx = (i) => {
    let countryName = "";
    let capitalName = "";
    let countryNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * cname.length);
    if (countryNum) {
      countryName = cname[countryNum].name;
      capitalName = cname[countryNum].capital;
      
    }
    namearray[i] = countryName;
    capitalArray[i] = capitalName;
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fx(i);
  }

  const shuffledAnswers = (currentQues) => {
    let shuffled = questions[currentQues].answerOptions
      .map((value) => ({ value, sort: Math.random() }))
      .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
      .map(({ value }) => value);
  // console.log(shuffled)
    return shuffled;
  };




  
  const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "What is the capital of " + namearray[0] + "?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: capitalArray[0], isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: capitalArray[1], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[2], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[3], isCorrect: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "What is the capital of " + namearray[1] + "?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: capitalArray[4], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[1], isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: capitalArray[0], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[3], isCorrect: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "What is the capital of " + namearray[2] + "?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: capitalArray[1], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[0], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[2], isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: capitalArray[3], isCorrect: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "What is the capital of " + namearray[3] + "?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: capitalArray[0], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[2], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[1], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[3], isCorrect: true },
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "What is the capital of " + namearray[4] + "?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: capitalArray[4], isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: capitalArray[1], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[2], isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: capitalArray[3], isCorrect: false },
      ],
    },
  ];
  const hoc = (isCorrect) => {
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      setScore(score + 1);
    }
    const nextq = currentQues + 1;
    if (nextq < questions.length) {
      setCurrentQues(nextq);
    } else {
      finalres(true);
    }

  
  };


 console.log('data')
  return (
    <>
      <h4>Quiz</h4>
      <div id="head">Welcome User</div>
      <hr />
      {results ? (
        <div className="final-res">
          Final Results
          <h4>you scored {score} out of 5</h4>
          <button onClick={() => restartGame()}>Restart</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div id="quescard">
            <h3>
              {currentQues + 1}. {questions[currentQues].questionText}
            </h3>
            {questions[currentQues].answerOptions.map((ansopt) => (
            
              <button onClick={() => hoc(ansopt.isCorrect)}>
                {ansopt.answerText}
                
              </button>


            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Quiz
```

Comment: Tried the same code in codesandbox and I can't see the API call is triggered on every button click useEffect block with empty dependency will only execute on componentDidMount

Comment: Hello, is your page refreshing on button click? If that is the case try setting type 'button'
<button type='button'></button> to prevent the page from refreshing. Also you can prevent the default if you pass event to your functions in the click listener:
event.preventDefault()
be it the case...

Comment: @Naveen on doing console.log it's showing that it is getting called on every option click

Comment: @ AtrimusMaximus No,it's not refreshing

Comment: @renumanwani inside useEffect block?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are updating the state of the component whenever any answer option is being clicked by making them buttons.

Instead make them checkboxes and add a additional button below which would allow the user to proceed with his final selection whereby which only allowing to update the state once

Comment: It's not working with this

Comment: It would be better if you could share the updated code